# Reading multiple QR Codes in iOS AVFoundation

Tags: ios, avfoundation, qr-code, ios-camera

I'm trying to create an application that detects all the QR Codes in my current camera frame, but am limited in that AVFoundation seems to only give me 4 QR Codes focused near the middle. Is it possible to detect more QR Codes simultaneously in one frame?

Code: pretty much [this](https://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

It seems you can use Vision to detect all QR codes in an image.

From the docs of `VNDetectBarcodesRequest`:

> By default, a barcode request first locates all barcodes in the input image, then analyzes each to decode payload.

(Note that even though it's named "barcodes", the `symbologies` also support QR.)

[This tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/12663654-vision-framework-tutorial-for-ios-scanning-barcodes) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I initally wanted to see if it was capable for the camera session to detect more than 4 qr codes in one frame, would you happen to know if that is possible? Otherwise, I am thinking of taking a snapshot when I detect at least 1 QR code and rendering an image to use the Vision framework

Comment: I don’t know, but I guess the capture session is more constrained to conserve resources for actual capture. Why don’t you use Vision on the camera feed directly like in the tutorial?

Comment: Mostly because I want to have my phone continue running to extract QR codes. So I want a real-time QR Code Scanner that will keep running. But I think it might be possible to keep taking images and running the Vision framework on every image that detects at least 1 QR code